# Socket.io is working on localhost but not working after deploying heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Here is the code of my socket server

```
const io = require("socket.io")(8080, {
cors: {
  // origin: "http://localhost:3000", 
     origin: "https://mern-bubble.herokuapp.com",
    }, 
});
```

and herer is my client side code

```
useEffect(() => {
   // socket.current = io("ws://localhost:8800");
      socket.current = io("ws://mern-bubble.herokuapp.com:8800");

       socket.current.on("getUser", (data) => {
       console.log("data from socket", data);
       dispatch(updateUserInfo(data));
    });
 }, [dispatch]);
```

It works completely fine when i am working on localhost, But when i deploy my project on heroku, socket.io is not responding anything ?

Answer (score 1):

So I think that port 8800 isn't open on heroku. You should stick to port 3000 and try again.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets#option-2-socket-io

Answer (score 1):

Heroku's port are dynamically assigned when starting a Dyno. Instead of hard coding the port `8800`, use the environment variable `$PORT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have entered the command:

`heroku features:enable http-session-affinity`

I was stuck on a similar problem when I had everything correct for days, I just needed to enable it on cli.
Reference - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets

On client side, you should enter the url of the site with https:// (conditionally depending on current window location or node_env value):

```
 const newSocket = io('https://my-app.herokuapp.com',
  { transports: ["websocket"] }
  );
```

On server side my MERN app worked by having a single server with a port of 5050 and not having to set anything in particular for the socket server:

```
  import { Server } from "socket.io";
  const server = http.createServer(app)
  export const io = new Server(server, {
      cors: {
        origin: 'https://my-app.herokuapp.com',
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        // allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
        credentials: true
      }
    })
```

If it works locally and all your urls are correct, try to enter the command mentioned above or look at the heroku node websocket documents.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your PORT like this.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3200
const io = require("socket.io")(port, {
cors: {
  // origin: "http://localhost:3000", 
     origin: "https://mern-bubble.herokuapp.com",
    }, 
});
```